# Why do these SQL Server queries produce different outcomes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

DATABASE: Adventure Works 2017

**Query #1:**

```
select 
    c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.EmailAddress,
    a.AddressID as addrId, addr.AddressLine1 as address 
from
    [AdventureWorksLT2017].[SalesLT].[Customer] c 
left join 
    (
        [AdventureWorksLT2017].[SalesLT].[CustomerAddress] a 
        inner join 
            [AdventureWorksLT2017].[SalesLT].[Address] addr 
        on addr.AddressID = a.AddressID
    ) 
    on c.CustomerID=a.CustomerID
where 
    c.EmailAddress = 'orlando0@adventure-works.com';
```

This is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJlmQ.png

**Query #2**

```
select 
    c.CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.EmailAddress,
    a.AddressID as addrId, addr.AddressLine1 as address 
from
    [AdventureWorksLT2017].[SalesLT].[Customer] c 
left join 
    [AdventureWorksLT2017].[SalesLT].[CustomerAddress] a 
    on a.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
inner join  
    [AdventureWorksLT2017].[SalesLT].[Address] addr 
    on addr.AddressID = a.AddressID
where 
    c.EmailAddress = 'orlando0@adventure-works.com';
```

This is the result of query #2:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwOdg.png

The desired result I want is the one from query #1, but I tried with the second query and I thought that it will produce the same result -  but ...

Can anyone explain why ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple, it's all about the join ordering.

Starting with the second version, we do the following steps

1. Take all `Customer`
2. Left join their `CustomerAddress`, so none of the previous rows have been removed
3. Inner join `Address` to steps 1 and 2, which means only rows that already have a match will be in the resultset

Whereas in version one:

1. Take all `Customer`
2. Take all `CustomerAddress`...
3. ...Inner join `Address` to step 2 only, which means only `CustomerAddress` rows that have a match with `Address` will be in the resultset
4. But then left join the *whole result* of 2 and 3, so none of step 1 `Customer` rows have been removed

This means that the first version will not remove `Customer` rows which do not have an `Address`, whereas version two will do so. Version one is more likely the correct intention

---

**Important note:**

The parenthesis themselves are not what does this. It's the fact that the `inner join` is nested between `left join` and its respective `on`. In other words, it's the order of the joins that counts.

Comment: oh i see, so lets say if i have any other query without joins and I am using APPLY instead with round parenthesis then those parenthesis will be resolved first and that result set would then be mapped against T1 or the top table in query ?

Comment: It's not the parenthesis, it's the order of the joins. An `APPLY` is always mapped row-by-row anyway. Note also that we are only discussing *logical* join ordering, not what the compiler physically does, which may be very different, but with the same result