# What is this "nested JOIN" syntax without a subquery called?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, nested

In SQL Server (T-SQL), I can JOIN to a subquery of course, but I just learned I can also JOIN to a nested JOIN expression that isn't a subquery.  For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer c
JOIN ( /* note no SELECT */
    dbo.Table2 t2 
    JOIN dbo.Table3 t3 ON t3.t2Id = t2.Id
) ON c.t2Id = t2.Id  /* note no alias */
WHERE c.CustomerId = 1234;
```

What is this "nested JOIN without subquery" syntax called and where can I find it in the Microsoft documentation?  It isn't mentioned in the context of [joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver16) or of [subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: A FROM clause subquery is called a _derived table_.

Comment: And ANSI/ISO SQL requires an alias.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see anything in the Microsoft documentation about "derived table" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?scope=sql&view=sql-server-ver16&terms=derived%20table), except for one page on Visual Database Tools, which is irrelevant here.

Comment: Oracle calls it _inline view_.

Comment: BTW, the no-SELECT syntax was removed from ANSI/ISO SQL ages ago.

Comment: All the non-Microsoft pages about "derived tables" are about full subqueries with a SELECT clause, which is not what I am asking about--so I think there's more to the answer here. Hmm...

Comment: You don't need the parehthesis afaik, perhaps [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/06/sql-performance/t-sql-bugs-pitfalls-best-practices-joins) is useful - *"Don’t confuse the use of parentheses here with a derived table. This isn’t a derived table, rather just a way to separate some of the table operators to their own unit, for clarity. The language doesn’t really need these parentheses, but they are strongly recommended for readability."*

Comment: Yes, this isn't really a subqeury, as Stu pointed out. Valid SQL standard syntax according to https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/.

Comment: I think the `( /* note no SELECT */
    dbo.Table2 t2 
    JOIN dbo.Table3 t3 ON t3.t2Id = t2.Id
) ` makes a temporary table and you can then still adress the columns within

Comment: This is valid according to the SQL Standard. I find this syntax a bit confusing, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: *Not a derived table. Not a subquery. Not a temp table.* What it does is logically defines the order that the joins are performed.  It has little utility with inner joins. **Where it really comes in useful is when used with outer joins.** An example use case might be "all orders left join to back-ordered products", but there is a junction table in between. There you might have `FROM Order O LEFT JOIN (OrderDetail OD JOIN Product P ON P.P_ID = OD.P_ID AND P.IsBackOrdered) ON OD.O_ID = O.O_ID`. This allows the order-detail and product rows to be combined before fed to the LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Not a derived table. Not a subquery. Not a temp table.* What it does is logically defines the order that the joins are performed. It has little utility with inner joins. **Where it really comes in useful is when used with outer joins.**

An example use case might be "all orders `left join` to back-ordered products", but where there is a junction table in between. This can be coded as:

```
...
FROM Order O
LEFT JOIN (
    OrderDetail OD
    JOIN Product P
        ON P.ProductId= OD.ProductId
        AND P.IsBackOrdered = 1 -- Not proper design, but it's just an example
    )
    ON OD.OrderId = O.OrderId
```

This allows the order-detail and product rows to be combined and filtered before being fed to the LEFT JOIN.

The parenthesis are actually optional, but I prefer to include them to somewhat improve readability (giving the reader a hint that something tricky is going on).

But as to "what is it called?" I don't think it has a name. I think of it as *grouped joins* or *out-of-order joins*. It's almost like the Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) of HP calculators back in the days of the HP-35 and successors.

Comment: Nice answer, @TN. I actually prefer the confusing select * from customer c LEFT JOIN Order o INNER JOIN OrderDetail od ON od.id = o.od ON o.id = c.id;

Comment: Any idea where Microsoft might document this?

Comment: In the `FROM` clause. I too had an HP RPN calculator. I remember the utter bafflement it caused when other people asked to borrow a calculator!

Answer (score 1):

> where can I find it in the Microsoft documentation?

In the [`FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause (as pointed out by [@mustaccio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227152/mustaccio) in this [cross site dupe](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125426/3690)).

Your `FROM` clause is

```
FROM   dbo.Customer c
       JOIN ( dbo.Table2 t2
              JOIN dbo.Table3 t3
                ON t3.t2Id = t2.Id )
         ON c.t2Id = t2.Id
```

Note the grammar for `joined_table` is

```
<joined_table> ::=
{
    <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition>
    ....
    | [ ( ] <joined_table> [ ) ]
}
```

So the following is a valid `<joined_table>`

```
 dbo.Table2 t2
  JOIN dbo.Table3 t3
    ON t3.t2Id = t2.Id
```

The above grammar also shows the optional parentheses that can be applied to a `<joined_table>` to produce another valid `<joined_table>` so this is also one

```
( dbo.Table2 t2
  JOIN dbo.Table3 t3
    ON t3.t2Id = t2.Id )
```

And also as shown further up in the grammar on that documentation page `<joined_table>` is also a valid `<table_source>`.

So you are just doing

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Customer c
       JOIN <joined_table>
         ON c.t2Id = t2.Id
```

and, somewhat recursively, using a `<joined_table>` as a `<table_source>` to produce a further `<joined_table>`.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are a table expression, and they mean you definitely want the server to complete that nested JOIN expression *before* the outer JOIN expression. For this query, where everything is an inner join, it's no different than listing the JOINs in the traditional way (just be careful of how you write the `ON` clauses):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer c
JOIN dbo.Table2 t2 ON c.t2Id = t2.Id
JOIN dbo.Table3 t3 on t3.t2Id = t2.Id
WHERE c.CustomerId = 1234;
```

The above query will give the same results, and is arguably much easier to read and maintain.

However, it's possible to use an `OUTER JOIN` inside the parenthetical expression to build the results in ways that are easier to write and understand than a query without parentheses.

Comment: According to the SQL Standard a "table expression" includes the SELECT & FROM clauses.

Comment: No it's not, it a join ordering thing - see the article Stu posted in the comments.

Comment: Note that the parenthesis are irrelevant, it's purely dependent on putting `JOIN ... JOIN ... ON ... ON...` ie the nesting of the `ON` clauses. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69427835/14868997

Comment: It would be more useful to explain what happens when a left join is involved as in the article posted.

Comment: Yeah its not technically a "table expression" as "Table expressions are named query expressions that represent a valid relational table." - so  [derived tables, common table expressions (CTEs), views, and inline table-valued functions](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233323) - but in the BNF grammar the symbol is called `<joined_table>` and it is used as a `<table_source>` in that context