# Understanding join ON placement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently looking at another person's code in order to make updates. I've noticed something I've never come across. They are joining multiple tables, but are putting the ON statements at the end at times. An example would be:

```
SELECT ID, Seq, Val1, Val2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table3 t3
   ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Is this interpreted the same as if I did something like this:

```
SELECT ID, Seq, Val1, Val2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq
```

Or should I be reading it differently?

Comment: With `INNER JOIN`s, yes. If you had `OUTER JOIN`s involved, no.

Comment: Honestly, from a ease of reading code, I would do how you were taught and tell the person to change to the more readable method.  Keeping the ON clauses near your joins is 100x easier to read as you write more complex code.

Comment: Written as they are, both these queries would give an ambiguous column error, but I doubt that is the *true* question you are asking.

Comment: It's a way of specifying the order joins are applied rather than strictly top to bottom. Sometimes you might need to make sure an inner join is done first before a left join. `A -> (B -- C)` This is one occasion where right join is useful. In fact you can use parentheses in the SQL as well. In your case it doesn't really matter.

Comment: This is the grouped JOIN case mentioned in [Grouping JOIN Clauses In SQL](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1059-grouping-join-clauses-in-sql.htm). This is essentially `INNER JOIN Table2 t2
(INNER JOIN Table3 t3  ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq)  ON t1.ID = t2.ID ` without the optional parentheses. I don't remember seeing this in 25 years and in *this* case it's not useful. In the article grouping is used to avoid converting a `LEFT JOIN` between the "primary" table and other tables into a RIGHT JOIN or subqueries. Personally, I use CTEs and RIGHT JOINs in such cases.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/e1hFUe6u from some examples using `(` and `)` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this "nested JOIN" syntax without a subquery called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76783203/what-is-this-nested-join-syntax-without-a-subquery-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the grouped JOIN case mentioned in [Grouping JOIN Clauses In SQL](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1059-grouping-join-clauses-in-sql.htm). When used properly, it can make queries cleaner and easier to read.

This is the same as the following clause without the optional parentheses:

```
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
    ( INNER JOIN Table3 t3  
      ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq
     )  
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

In this case it's not useful and just makes the entire query harder to read. In the article's example though, it actually makes the query *cleaner*.

Let's say we want to list all companies along with any contacts that have phone numbers.

```
DECLARE @company TABLE ( 
    id INT,name VARCHAR( 30 )
);

DECLARE @contact TABLE (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR( 30 ),
    company_id INT
);

DECLARE @phone TABLE (
    name VARCHAR( 30 ),
    contact_id INT
);

INSERT INTO @company(id,    name)
values
    (1, 'Nylon Technology'),
    (2, 'Edit.com'), 
    (3, 'HotKoko')
;

INSERT INTO @contact(id,name,company_id)
VALUES 
    (1, 'Maria Bello', 1  ),
    (2, 'Christina Cox', 1),
    (3, 'Julia Stiles', 2 ),
    (4, 'Julie Ensike', 3 )
;

INSERT INTO @phone( name,   contact_id)
VALUES
    ('123-456-1890', 1),
    ('123-456-5555', 4)
;
```

We can't use all `LEFT JOIN`s, that would return contacts without numbers. We can't use a LEFT JOIN followed by an INNER JOIN, that would only return companies with phone contacts :

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    ( ct.name ) AS contact_name,
    ( p.name ) AS contact_phone
FROM
    @company c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @contact ct
ON
    c.id = ct.company_id
INNER JOIN
    @phone p
ON
    ct.id = p.contact_id;
---
id  name    contact_name    contact_phone
1   Nylon Technology    Maria Bello 123-456-1890
3   HotKoko Julie Ensike    123-456-5555
```

Using grouped JOINs, the query works and is easy to read:

```
FROM
    @company c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        @contact ct
        INNER JOIN
            @phone p
        ON
            ct.id = p.contact_id
    )
    ON
        c.id = ct.company_id
---
id  name    contact_name    contact_phone
1   Nylon Technology    Maria Bello 123-456-1890
2   Edit.com    NULL    NULL
3   HotKoko Julie Ensike    123-456-5555
```

An alternative would be either to use a subquery, or reverse the table order and use RIGHT JOIN

```
FROM
    @phone p
INNER JOIN
    @contact ct
ON
    p.contact_id = ct.id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    @company c
ON
    ct.company_id = c.id
```

This time the "primary" table appears last, making the query harder to read.

I left the subquery example for last because it's really hard to read. The SELECT clause must be duplicated :

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    t.contact_name,
    t.contact_phone
FROM
    @company c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            ct.company_id,
            ( ct.name ) AS contact_name,
            ( p.name ) AS contact_phone
        FROM
            @contact ct
        INNER JOIN
            @phone p
        ON
            ct.id = p.contact_id
    ) AS t
ON
    c.id = t.company_id
```

This example can be simplified a bit using a CTE but it's still not as clean as the grouped JOINs:

```
WITH contact_phones as (        
    SELECT
        ct.company_id,
        ( ct.name ) AS contact_name,
        ( p.name ) AS contact_phone
    FROM
        @contact ct
    INNER JOIN
        @phone p
    ON
        ct.id = p.contact_id
)
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    t.contact_name,
    t.contact_phone
FROM
    @company c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    contact_phones AS t
ON
    c.id = t.company_id
```

Answer (score 2):

For the 2 queries you have, yes they are identical. They would both error with an error like:

> Ambiguous column name 'ID'.
>
> Ambiguous column name 'Seq'.

This is because you don't qualify any column in your `SELECT` and both `table1` and `table2` have a column `ID`. `Table2` and `Table3` also both have a column `Seq`. As a result the data engine doesn't know what column you want (even if they will have the same value).

If they ran (you qualified the columns) they would generate the same results. Very likely, if you inspect the plans you'll also see that they are, infact, identical.

If, however, you had `OUTER JOIN`s involved, then this would not be true. Take, for example, the following:

```sql
--Query 1
SELECT t1.ID,
       t2.Seq,
       t3.Val1,
       t3.Val2
FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
                INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq
                        ON t1.ID = t2.ID 

--Query 2
SELECT t1.ID,
       t2.Seq,
       t3.Val1,
       t3.Val2
FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
     INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq
```

These queries are **not** identical. In fact, the latter query is actually identical to your queries (if they were valid). This is because in the top query the second `ON` is "deferred". As a result a data set with an `INNER JOIN` between `Table2` and `Table3` is determined, and then that data is `LEFT JOIN`ed to `Table1`. This means that all rows from `Table1` would still be returned. On the other hand, for the 2nd query, the `LEFT JOIN` to `Table2` is actually an implicit `INNER JOIN`. This is because of the `INNER JOIN` to `Table3` which required a row from `Table2` to be found. As a result a row in `Table2` *must* be found for the row to be returned. This means that only rows from `Table1` are returned when related rows in *both* `Table2` *and* `Table3` are found.

Query 2, is therefore, closer to a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID,
       t2.Seq,
       t3.Val1,
       t3.Val2
FROM Table2 t2 
     INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq
     RIGHT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

So, here, the rows from `Table1` will still be returned regardless of if rows in `Table2` and `Table3` are found, but data from `TAble2` will only be returned if the related row is found in `Table3`.

The syntax, for query 2, *is* also similar to the following:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID,
       t23.Seq,
       t23.Val1,
       t23.Val2
FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                FROM Table2 t2
                     INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq) T23 ON T1.ID = T23.ID;
```

There is a problem with that query though, it has at least 2 columns with the same name (`ID`), and so would error. YOu would need to be specific in the subquery on what columns you wanted:

```sql
SELECT t1.ID,
       t23.Seq,
       t23.Val1,
       t23.Val2
FROM Table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.ID,
                       t3.Val1,
                       t3.Val2
                FROM Table2 t2
                     INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID AND t2.Seq = t3.Seq) T23 ON T1.ID = T23.ID;
```

Personally, I don't often use these `JOIN`, but there has been occasion. Some prefer using syntax like the above and using a `LEFT JOIN` to a derived table, or an `OUTER APPLY` to a correlated subquery. Others use `RIGHT JOIN`s, but I tend to avoid those.#

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DaFtJ7Km) containing examples, and demonstrating identical plans for similar queries.